# How to place text on top of CSS custom shape?

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/77af3/

I use CSS3 :after to create a custom shape:
a rectangle on top of a triangle.
The text that I need is inside of the rectangle
and should be on top of the triangle.
However, the bottom part of letters gets covered
by the triangle.
I wonder if it is possible to place the text
on top of both figures using CSS.

```
.position   {
border-style: 1px solid red;
z-index:1;
color:white;
font-size:20px;
text-align:center;
background:red;
height: 16px;
width: 32px;
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
padding-top:2px;
}

.position:after   {
content: "";
z-index:0;
position: absolute;
top: 18px;
left: 0px;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-left: 16px solid transparent;
border-right: 16px solid transparent;
border-top: 16px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your font size was 20px, your height was 16px, your triangle technically wasn't covering anything, there just isn't enough room to display your text as the text size was too large for the amount of space you gave it. Increase the height of your box to that of your font size.

http://jsfiddle.net/77af3/3/

```
.position   {
  border-style: 1px solid red;
  z-index:1;
  color:white;
  font-size:20px;
  text-align:center;
  background:red;
  height: 20px;
  width: 32px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top:2px;
}
.position:after   {
  content: "";
  z-index:0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 16px solid transparent;
  border-right: 16px solid transparent;
  border-top: 16px solid red;
}
```

Personally I would advise against using z-index's and such to force it to look like it's rendering okay. Always make sure the container you're putting text in is naturally large enough to accommodate it, otherwise you'll only run into other issues later on such as some letters clipping over the edges (here's an example of that problem occuring when using a z-index solution http://jsfiddle.net/77af3/7/)

Answer (score 0):

change the `z-index:0` to  `z-index:-1`

Try this code:

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/RQ64x/)**:

```
.position   {
    border-style: 1px solid red;
    z-index:1;
    color:white;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;
    background:red;
    height: 16px;
    width: 32px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top:2px;
}
.position:after   {
    content: "";
    z-index:-1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 18px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 16px solid transparent;
    border-right: 16px solid transparent;
    border-top: 16px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `z-index:-1`. However, this will be placed behind all elements in page.

**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZsfJZ/)**

Alternatively, you can make the height of the text container bigger with `line-height:value` or `height:value` and place the `:after` pseudo-element lower so that it will not override the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can check below link :

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/77af3/1/)

```
.position   {
border-style: 1px solid red;
z-index:1;
color:white;
font-size:20px;
line-height:15px;
text-align:center;
background:red;
height: 18px;
width: 32px;
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;

}
.position:after   {
content: "";
z-index:0;
position: absolute;
top: 18px;
left: 0px;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-left: 16px solid transparent;
border-right: 16px solid transparent;
border-top: 16px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't do it the way you want it. But there are alternatives.

I made this:

http://jsfiddle.net/77af3/4/

Wrap a `span` on the text so that you can manipulate it much easier. I guess this will be good enough for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

How about that?

```
.position {
    color: transparent;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;
    width: 32px;
    height: 16px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top:2px;
    background:red;
}
.position:before   {
    content: "MF";
    color:white;
    width: 32px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:1;
    top: 1px;
}
.position:after   {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index:0;
    top: 16px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 16px solid transparent;
    border-right: 16px solid transparent;
    border-top: 16px solid red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/77af3/5/

Answer (score 0):

Try putting z-index in .position:after as -1

```
.position   {
    border-style: 1px solid red;
    z-index:2;
    color:white;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;
    background:red;
    height: 16px;
    width: 32px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top:2px;

}
.position:after   {
    content: "";
    z-index:-1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 18px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 16px solid transparent;
    border-right: 16px solid transparent;
    border-top: 16px solid red;
}

.text {
    z-index:100;
}
```

Check this:

http://jsfiddle.net/77af3/6/

Hope I helped a bit.